# Flutter / App development beginner seeking wisdom, general direction

Tags: android, flutter

I am a student working on a senior project.  It will be a very simple android app to organize karaoke.  We are using Flutter for the front-end work.

My education has been in Java, but this is my first time working with Dart/Flutter, let alone on a smartphone app.  I have gone through Get Started (https://flutter.io/get-started/), as well as 2-3 step-by-step youtube tutorials that help you build very simple apps from scratch.  These have been helpful, but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around the organization of a Flutter app.  All tutorials say "everything is a widget", as if that should make things simple.  And maybe it does in the end.  But I end up with so many widgets, and I am getting confused about what widget should be inside what other widget and why.

Take a look at this picture (in the middle of the picture I have the widget-tree on display).  I have a stack, two columns, scaffold, container, etc.  Do I really need all of those?  Is this normal for a simple login page?

What helped you get a grip on Flutter?  Or maybe it is app development, rather, that I am having trouble understanding.  Regardless, I am getting a bit discouraged.  Any advice?  Maybe there is a particular tutorial that helped you a lot?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It looks like you need to be patient and keep on studying, Flutter's approach, specially on design is a bit awkward at first. Then you'll have trouble to understand async programming with dart, but that's part of learning a new language/framework. [this link is full of useful stuff](https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter)

Comment: Well, looks like I forgot to link the picture.  Oops.

Thank you for the link.  Yeah I'll just keep on chugging I guess.  I hate learning new things. :)

Comment: Having tons of widgets is normal. This is how flutter works. You use smaller wigets to create bigger ones, to create even biggers. Flutter is a mixture of imperative and functional programming. I guess you haven't touched functional before, maybe try reading about that.

Comment: Functional programming, got it.  Looking it up now.

Answer (score 0):

I like to learn by downloading and running examples from the developers (like these ones in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples)).

One thing I struggled with at first too from the whole "everything is a widget" idea was figuring out how to handle state / data changes appropriately. If you're struggling with that, [this Google I/O video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI) does a great job showing how you can better architect an app in regard to handling state in a reactive way. A bit more advanced, but from beginning to end they go from their opinion on the worst way to handle state changes to their recommended way(s).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm only 7 minutes into the video but I can already tell it will be very helpful.